# Filter an NSArray of files?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

Given an following files in the Documents directory --

```
Animals/Birds/file1.xyz
Animals/Birds/file2.xyz
Animals/Cats/file1.xyz
Cars/Ford/file1.xyz
Photos/MyAlbums/file1.xyz
```

And given that we have an `NSArray` of `NSURLs` to these files, is it possible to use an `NSPredicate` to filter the array by path or path/subpath? For example

- Unique names of everything in the first level of the hierarchy (Animals, Cars, Photos)
- Unique names of everything in the second level (Birds, Cats)
- Files in the Animals directory -- (/Animals)
- Files in the Cats directory -- (/Animals/Cats)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are actual file URLs in the actual Documents directory, why not use NSFileManager `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:`? It directly answers the question you are asking ("files in the Cats directory").

Or, for more power, cycle through the files with an NSDirectoryEnumerator.

Comment: Mostly for performance reasons. The array is part of a `UICollectionViewDataDource` which switches (via pinch) between showing the various levels. I could simply iterate through the first level and wait for a pinch gesture to determine what's in the second level -- but there are an unknown number of files or directories. Since using an `NSPredicate` to filter an array is fairly lightweight, my thought was to grab all the files at the beginning and filter the list when the collection view needs counts and objects from a particular level in the hierarchy.

Comment: Or perhaps a better question might have been what's the most performant approach to use if you want to display various levels of a directory structure in `UICollectionView`.

Comment: You're just making me repeat myself. Have you any actual *reason* to doubt that `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:` is "performant"? It *directly* answers the question, *instantly*. Alternatively, you should have started with a more appropriate data structure, one from which you could extract this information instantly - something hierarchical and random-access. As it stands, the file system *is* hierarchical and random-access, and will do better than your flat array.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to filter an array of NSURLs you could do something like this:

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArray:(NSArray *)originalArray withSubpath:(NSString *)subpath {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSURL *url = (NSURL *)evaluatedObject;
        NSRange range = [[url path] rangeOfString:subpath];
        return (range.location == 0);
    }];
    return [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Here's how I tested it:

```
NSArray *urls = @[[NSURL URLWithString:@"Animals/Birds/file1.xyz"],
                  [NSURL URLWithString:@"Animals/Birds/file2.xyz"],
                  [NSURL URLWithString:@"Animals/Cats/file1.xyz"],
                  [NSURL URLWithString:@"Cars/Ford/file1.xyz"]];

NSLog(@"Before: %@", urls);
urls = [self filteredArray:urls withSubpath:@"Animals/Birds"];
NSLog(@"After: %@", urls);
```

The output log was:

```
Before: (
    "Animals/Birds/file1.xyz",
    "Animals/Birds/file2.xyz",
    "Animals/Cats/file1.xyz",
    "Cars/Ford/file1.xyz"
)
After: (
    "Animals/Birds/file1.xyz",
    "Animals/Birds/file2.xyz"
)
```

**Note**: It matches substrings, so it wouldn't match "/Animals" in this case because of the leading slash (unless both the array and the substring included the '/').